Trackers on U&L SE?
This may be an issue with "SE Headquarters", but I'll report it here as this is where I've seen it:
I am getting notifications from a couple of sources regarding trackers, etc on U&L SE. I'm reporting this because I've been using SE for years, and have never seen these notifications until very recently.
"Privacy Badger" reports 6 trackers:
cdn.cookielaw.org
graph.facebook.com
pagead2.googlesyndication.com
www.googletagmanager.com
lh5.googleusercontent.com
www.gravatar.com
"uBlockOrigin" reports 2 blocked sites:
googlesyndication.com
googletagmanager.com
When I see the word "google", I become "annoyed"; perhaps I'm prejudiced?... But yes - I do think that Google Sucks!!
My question is this: Has this site (U&L SE), or "SE Headquarters" recently hired Google to begin tracking its users?

Related from two years ago: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377822/stop-tracking-users-without-their-consent

In general, questions such as this belongs on the main Meta site, not out on the U&L branch of the tree.

@Kusalananda: As I said in the first sentence of my Q...

I'll tag our SE support team and see if they can shed any light.

Stack Overflow and our Stack Exchange sites have some tracking in regards to ads. This is not something new, and no recent changes have been made.

@Dalmarus: Well gee - it must be those pesky Extensions on Firefox. I guess they must have been sleeping - or just goofing off - for all these years. Funny they both seemed to wake up at the same time.  Sarcasm aside for a moment, I'd like to know WHY SE feels it necessary to track all of its users? Is this something you get paid for - tracking us, I mean?

@Seamus this has been discussed at great length on the main meta (IMO, SE haven't given a particularly good answer, but it does seem like they're mostly getting usage information). See Stop tracking users without their consent, Why is the Google Analytics cookie defined as "strictly necessary" and saved without consent?, Is the company selling our Personal Information or not? and various others.
